# How to print the long dictionary in to seperate lines

Tags: python, dictionary

How to print the long dictionary in to separate lines

```
test = {'db1': [{'url': 'http://localhost:8080/api', 'cmd': 'test\\nshow databases ', 'request': 'POST'}], 'db2': [{'url': 'http://localhost:8080/api', 'cmd': 'test\\nshow databases ', 'request': 'POST'}]}
```

Expected output

```
test = 
{'db1':[{'url': 'http://localhost:8080/api', 'cmd': 'test\\nshow databases', 'request': 'POST'}],
 'db2': [{'url': 'http://localhost:8080/api', 'cmd': 'test\\nshow databases', 'request': 'POST'}]}
```

By importing json module is printing is giving the same output
as normal print (test)

```
import json
print (json.dumps(test))
```

Comment: Use `pprint.pprint(test)`?

Comment: If you just want to print one key-value-pair per line that can be done with: `for k,v in test.items(): print('%s: %s' % (k, v))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your just want to "pretty-print" your dictionary, [set the `indent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) parameter of the `json.dumps` function:

```
>>> import json
>>> test = {'db1': [{'url': 'http://localhost:8080/api', 'cmd': 'test\\nshow databases ', 'request': 'POST'}], 'db2': [{'url': 'http://localhost:8080/api', 'cmd': 'test\\nshow databases ', 'request': 'POST'}]}
>>> print(json.dumps(test, indent=2))
{
  "db1": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/api",
      "cmd": "test\\nshow databases ",
      "request": "POST"
    }
  ],
  "db2": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/api",
      "cmd": "test\\nshow databases ",
      "request": "POST"
    }
  ]
}
```